# App se detiene al usar Connectivity manager

Tags: java, android

Tengo una clase en la que pretnedo ver si el usuario está o no conectado. No obstante, el método completo no funcionaba, por lo que fui quitando cosas para ver cuál era el problema y he visto que tan solo con el código de esta manera la app se detiene al ejecutarla:

```
public class Conectividad 
{
    static Context context;
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract(value = " -> false", pure = true)
    public static boolean conectado()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return false;
    }
}
```

En cuanto a la llamada a dicho método, simplemente hago lo siguiente:  `if(Conectividad.conectado()==false)`

En su momento probé a hacerlo todo en la misma clase, pero ello, aunque hacía que funcionara eso, hacía que la pantalla se quedara en blanco al ejecutarlo. El método anterior en cuestión era el siguiente:

```
 public static boolean conectado()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        return (info!=null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting());
    }
```

Y la llamada al mismo era: `if(conectado()==false)`.

Por otro lado, en el manifest tengo añadido

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Ninguno de estos dos métodos me ha funcionado. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer que esto funcione?

Comment: Porque no agregas el LogCat???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto tiene pinta de que has olvidado añadir el permiso correspondiente para poder comprobar el estado de la red:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Puedes utilizar el siguiente código para comprobar si está conectado o no

```
public boolean conectado() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity  = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable() && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected());
 }
```

**EDITADO**

Revisando tu código me he dado cuenta que estás utilizando el `context` que tiene definido en tu clase `Conectividad` pero no has puesto si ese parámetro le has dado valor en algún sitio. Una alternativa para solucionar esto seria que en vez de definirlo en tu clase `Conectividad` pases el context de la Actividad como parámetro cada vez que quieras comprobar la conexión, quedando tu función de la siguiente forma:

```
public static boolean conectado(Context context)
{
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        return (info!=null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting());
}
```

Comment: El permiso ya lo tengo añadido. En cuanto al código que has puesto, también lo probé, pero el resultado fue el mismo.

Comment: Ok, voy a  ver si se me ocurre cuál puede ser tu problema

Comment: @pepito revisa la edición de mi respuesta, creo que puede ser la causa de tu fallo

Comment: Parece que funciona, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudarte! Saludos

Comment: Siento volver a molestar, pero resulta que ahora me está dando un problema muy extraño, y es que si lo pongo en un if, la parte de true funciona bien, pero la de false no, cuando la única diferencia entre ambas es que en una se lanza un cuadro de diálogo y en la otra no.¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola @pepito necesitaría más información o ver ese trozo de código, crea una nueva pregunta si crees que el tema puede dar para una pregunta y gustosamente te ayudaré, sino podemos hablarlo en el chat

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de cuál era el problema el cual era ajeno a este. Tu solución funciona perfectamente así que muchas gracias y siento las molestias.

Comment: No es molestia, estamos aquí para ayudarnos. Saludos!